# Case sensitive string comparison in NSIS

Tags: scripting, operators, nsis

```
${If} $9 == $8
```

The above script in NSIS does a case **insensitive** string comparison, how can I ensure the comparison is made case **sensitive**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the case-sensitive operator:  `S==`

From  [Logiclib](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LogicLib#Expressions) documentation:

> Case-sensitive string tests (using System.dll):
>
> a S== b; a S!= b